# Reduce size of "if-else" loop

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is a way to reduce the size of this loop. I am looking for conditions in increments of +10, then loading an image accordingly, also in X,Y coordinates of +10 from the previous one. Thanks in advance.

```
  if (xpos >= 80){
  image(imgRainCloud, 90, 10);
  }
  if (xpos >= 90){
  image(imgBlock, 90, 10);
  image(imgRainCloud, 100, 10);
  }
  if(xpos >= 100){
  image(imgBlock, 100, 10);
  image(imgRainCloud, 110, 10);
  }
  if(xpos >= 110){
  image(imgBlock, 110, 10);
  image(imgRainCloud, 120, 10);
  }
  if(xpos >= 120){
  image(imgBlock, 120, 10);
  image(imgRainCloud, 130, 10);
  }
  if(xpos >= 130){
  image(imgBlock, 130, 10);
  image(imgRainCloud, 140, 10);
  }
  if(xpos >= 140){
  image(imgBlock, 140, 10);
  image(imgRainCloud, 150, 10);
  }
  else(xpos < 80){
  image(imgBlock, 0, 0);
  image(imgRainCloud, 0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: `if else..` is not a loop..

Comment: I must say that I have neither heard about an “if-else loop” nor the language “C / Java”.

Comment: you aren't using else statements so each if line is being evaluated even when a match is met.

Comment: The first two conditions use `>=`, the others use `>`. Intentional or not?

Comment: not intentional, thanks

Comment: edits made to address >= and lack of "else". I put Java and C because this is generic code, it is actually in Processing/Java-based.

Comment: @user3352354: Ir may look like it, but something as generic code between C++ and Java don´t exist. C++ is tricky sometimes, in that case eg. variable types (size, unsigned etc.) could get a problem. And maybe look again at your not-existing else-chain.

Comment: Are these `if`s really intended to be `if`s or should they be `else if`s?

Comment: You should debug this. Are you really trying to call image(imgRainCloud, x, y) 7 times when xpos is 140 or greater? I highly doubt that.

Comment: I still see no "else", so if you have a value of, say 125, many blocks and clouds are drawn, because 125 > 80, 125 > 90, 125 > 100, 125 > 110 and 125 > 120, so all these conditions apply.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (xpos >= 80){
    image(imgRainCloud, 90, 10);

    for (int i = 90; xpos >= i; i+=10)
    {
        image(imgBlock, i, 10);
        image(imgRainCloud, i+10, 10);
    }
}
else
{
    image(imgBlock, 0, 0);
    image(imgRainCloud, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can break them the if and else into different sets
eg:

```
if (xpos > 110) {

    image(imgBlock, 110, 10);
    image(imgRainCloud, 120, 10);
    if (xpos > 120) {

        image(imgBlock, 120, 10);
        image(imgRainCloud, 130, 10);

    }

    if (xpos > 130) {

        image(imgBlock, 130, 10);
        image(imgRainCloud, 140, 10);

    }

    if (xpos > 140) {

        image(imgBlock, 140, 10);
        image(imgRainCloud, 150, 10);

    }

} else {

    if (xpos >= 80) {

        image(imgRainCloud, 90, 10);

    }

    if (xpos >= 90) {

        image(imgBlock, 90, 10);
        image(imgRainCloud, 100, 10);

    }

    if (xpos > 100) {

        image(imgBlock, 100, 10);
        image(imgRainCloud, 110, 10);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that xpos is an integer, and assuming your code sample is missing a bunch of else statements, you could potentially do the following:

```
int range = xpos / 10;
if (range > 14)
    range = 14;
if (range >= 8)
{
    image(imgBlock, range*10, 10);
    image(imgRainCloud, (range+1)*10, 10);
}
else
{
    image(imgBlock, 0, 0);
    image(imgRainCloud, 0, 0);
}
```

You could also divide by ten, and then use a switch statement.